# "TypeError: elem is null" on autocmd'ed events.feedkey function

Tags: javascript, vimperator

The following line is causing the error:

```
autocmd LocationChange .* js events.feedkeys("<Esc>",true)
```

when I switch pages. Typing `js events.feedkeys("",true)` directly into the command line does not output any error messages. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not directly answer the question, but the behavior I was looking for was enabled by

```
 set focuscontent
```